# How to download tensorflow models in a nginx docker gunicorn django webapp?

Tags: django, docker, tensorflow, nginx, gunicorn

I have an nginx docker gunicorn django web app that requires some models to be downloaded from tensorflow, but, as people may see, the current configuration does not allow enough time for it to be downloaded.

My current gunicorn file (may not be a problem, because it should give time enough, but somehow it doesn't):

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:8000'
workers = 60
timeout = 3600
module = 'production.wsgi'
chdir = '/app'
forwarded_allow_ips = '*'
proxy_allow_ips = '*'
```

In the development stage, prior to this production stage, there was no problem in waiting a first long download to have this files locally.

Now in production, the container gives me this error.

```
Downloading (…)lve/main/config.json: 100%|██████████| 571/571 [00:00<00:00, 2.67MB/s]
Downloading model.safetensors:   4%|▍         | 52.4M/1.34G [00:20<08:25, 2.56MB/s]     [2023-07-16 05:45:06 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7)
site.com.br_1  | [2023-07-16 02:45:06 -0300] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
Downloading model.safetensors:   4%|▍         | 52.4M/1.34G [00:21<09:02, 2.38MB/s]
site.com.br_1  | [2023-07-16 05:45:07 +0000] [138] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 138
```

What is the correct approach? I think I need to force the download, probably thru the Dockerfile file ahead, but i cannot grasp how to do it, so how to correctly download this files and, to be more precise, from where to download them or, if this is not possible, how to make my server wait for these files to be downloaded?

My current Dockerfile:

```
# Use Python 3 as base image
FROM python:3

# Update packages and install necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev libicu-dev python3-tk r-base libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Upgrade pip and install Python packages
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install mysqlclient numpy

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Set Locale
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

# Install required R packages
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages(c('textshaping', 'ragg', 'tm', 'SnowballC', 'wordcloud', 'RColorBrewer', 'syuzhet', 'ggplot2', 'magrittr', 'quanteda',     'rainette', 'tidyverse'), repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"

# Copy requirements.txt and .env to the /app directory
COPY requirements.txt .env /app/

# Install project dependencies
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Download Spacy language models
RUN python3 -m spacy download pt_core_news_sm
RUN python3 -m spacy download es_core_news_sm
RUN python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

# Copy the rest of the files to the /app directory
COPY . /app/

# Set the necessary environment variables
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=production.settings

# Run Django migrations
RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
RUN python3 manage.py makemigrations
RUN python3 manage.py migrate

# Expose port 8000 for Gunicorn
EXPOSE 8000

# Start Gunicorn server with Django
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "production.wsgi:application"]
```

Thanks in advance!